# How to pass a specific variable to go back to the previous page when the browser back button is pressed (In Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, onclick, ejs

I know how to implement a function that goes back to the previous page and takes a certain variable when a certain button is clicked.

```
// The 2 at the end of the url is the variable I want to pass.

<button onclick='location.href="a link that prev page has/2"'> Back to prev page </button>
```

However, I do not know how to pass a specific variable while returning to the previous page when the back button, which is implemented by default in the Chrome browser, is pressed.

I am trying to get the variable passed from the previous page I returned to and use it. What should I do when I click the browser back button?

If there are different functions to be implemented depending on the browser, it would be thankful if you could tell us about it as well.

+) Each page is implemented as a separate ejs file.

Comment: You could listen for the `beforeunload` event and store the data in a localStorage entry.

Comment: `window.history.back()` is the actual API to go to the last page.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reload the previous page and know the path i would rather construct the link

```
 const new_location = location.origin + '/page'
 const new_url = new URL(new_location) 
 new_url.searchParams('param1','value')
 location = new_url
```

then node side you can use

```
 const {param1} = req.query
```